How to choose Duty Cycle value for a Full-Bridge DC/DC Converter
I've noticed that while designing DC/DC converters, some sources (at the bottom of the website, comment of Benjamin Lough) suggest a "rule of thumb" duty cycle of 70%, while others (This is a book from Robert W. Erickson and Dragan Maksimovic named Fundamentals of Power Electronics) (p.496 - Example 2) mention 75%. Additionally, in some theses and articles (p.48), I've seen that a duty cycle of around 70% is initially assumed, but later recalculated. I couldn't find an explanation for this anywhere.
I assume that this value might be:

Chosen around 70% to allow dead time, depending on the topology used,
Related to ZVS/ZCS. Although I know what they are, my understanding of their practical implications is limited.
Related to CCM/DCM.

Can someone enlighten me on this?
Thank you in advance!

There needs to be much more context to this question. A schematic would help. Additionally a statement on the type of PWM used and, finally, aims need to be stated. After all, nearly 100% can be used at full power ("near" means about 99% to avoid shoot-through). So, what do you need enlightening on?

I will ask this again tomorrow in a better way by providing schematic. But my question was where this 70% duty cycle comes from? Why it is chosen as 70% or around in sources I provided. Is it comes from the related things I wrote up there?

Well, assuming forward converter, what does duty cycle determine? When would we need more than "100%" and therefore run into a limit?

So you basically have a two part question here: Is 70% optimal and where does it come from? This too vague to answer because it varies depending on application. We did a measurement one time for our customers and found out that 40% was the best duty cycle for transients and voltage droop for the particular application and design that they made.

That being said, I recommend that you should talk with a supplier and asking their recommendations, or perhaps measurements, maybe for your application.
